# Sorting children by value in Orm

Tags: orm, cfml, lucee

I know I can set a specific `orderby` attribute when creating components, and I can add the same to a `EntityLoad` method. What if I have to sort somehow the children of a entity?

```
<cfset u = entityLoadByPk('user', 1)>
<cfset p = u.getPages()> <!-- sort by date? -->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `orderBy` attribute in your relationship property definition:

```
component name="user" accessors=true persistent=true{

 property name="pages" fieldType="one-to-many" cfc="Page" fkColumn="userID" orderBy="date";

}
```

### EDIT

The above will set the default ordering of the child entities. To allow other ordering options you could create a page ordering method within the User entity using `OrmExecuteQuery()`:

```
array function pagesOrdered( string column="", string direction="ASC" ){
 //use an array to build up the HQL string
 var hql=[ "FROM Page WHERE User.ID = :userID" ];
 //only allow ordering on specified columns
 if( "title,viewcount,updated".ListFindNoCase( arguments.column ) ){
  hql.Append( "ORDER BY " & arguments.column );
 }
 if( arguments.direction IS NOT "ASC" ){
  hql.Append( "DESC" );
 }
 hql=hql.ToList( " " );
 return OrmExecuteQuery( hql, { userID: variables.ID } );
}
```

Or for a slightly more concise but less orthodox approach, try a hibernate filter:

```
array function pagesOrdered( string column="", string direction="ASC" ){
 //use an array to build up the filter
 var filterString=[ "ORDER BY" ];
 //only allow ordering on specified columns
 if( "title,viewcount,updated".ListFindNoCase( arguments.column ) ){
  filterString.Append( arguments.column );
 } else {
  filterString.Append( "dateCreated" );
 }
 if( arguments.direction IS "DESC" ){
  filterString.Append( "DESC" );
 }
 return OrmGetSession().createFilter( variables.pages,filterString.ToList( " " ) ).list();
}
```

Comment: Thanks CfSimplicity, so if I want to sort for example result tables, by name Asc or Desc, I guess the only solution is resorting to `ORMExecuteQuery`

Comment: You can certainly use `ORMExecuteQuery()` to produce ordered results. But your question's about child relationships. You can specify ASC or DESC in the relationship's orderBy attribute, e.g. `orderBy="date DESC"`

Comment: Thanks CfSimplicity, what I am interested in is, how could I flip after say a page refresh the order of children, when a user clicks on 'change order' or something like that

Comment: OK, I didn't quite get that from your question. I've updated my answer with a couple of suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, there were some errors with parens/braces in my updated code.